# Convexity of Composite Function

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, function-and-relation-composition

Given two functions, $f$ and $g$, both convex, and additionally $f$ is increasing. 
Using the fact that if a function is differentiable and convex on an interval, then such function is, on the interval, either increasing, or decreasing, or there is a number c such that $f$ is decreasing to the left of it and increasing to the right of it, prove that $(f\circ g)$ is convex.

**What I know/tried:**

I know that if I show that, given $x<y$, $f'(g(x))g'(x)<f'(g(y))g'(y)$ as it shows that the derivative is increasing, and consequently a convex function. Playing around with the possible configurations for $x$ and $y$ seems to be the strategy, but I only achieved, using the convexity of $g$ and $f$, and the increasing aspect of the function $f$, that the derivative of the composite function is positive if $x<y<c$ and $c<x<y$, which isn't enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiation is neither necessary nor useful here.  For any $x, y$ and 
$0 \le t \le 1$, by definition of convex function $g(tx + (1-t)y) \le t g(x) + (1-t) g(y)$ so since $f$ is increasing, 
$$ f(g(tx + (1-t)y)) \le f(t g(x) + (1-t) g(y)) \le t f(g(x)) + (1-t) f(g(y))$$

Comment: Yes, I agree that's easier. Doing that way was a previous problem, but the text specifically asks for a solution using it.